# jQuery dialog modal opens every time on pageload during click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery's Modal dialog popup on page-load to display a message, and upon closing the modal, i am displaying my page, with couple of buttons on the page.

When I click on any of those buttons, the modal dialog opens up, and it opens on any click_event on the page.  I am not sure how to deactivate the modal dialog on every click_event of the same page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 189,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
               Agree: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

and my html is :

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="PLEASE READ BEFORE PROCEDDING" 
        style="font-weight: bold">
     <p>Documentation is MANDATORY!</p>
     <p>Please remember to list the PCP and Radiology Services Visited with the 
           and TIME included.  Please select “Agree” to continue.
     </p>
</div>
```

I searched this forum for similar issues, but haven't found any solution for this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your page reloading on every click?

Comment: Can we see a bit more of the HTML?

Comment: @Gjohn: Yes, I'm posting back to the same page, for ex, i have a gridview with select command, and based on the selection, i am showing records on the same page.

Comment: @mikehomme: The aspx page has some server controls with buttons and gridviews...

Comment: Ok, can you view source of the page, then post it here? Or better yet, create a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @mikehomme: I am not sure whether i could use JSFiddle to recreate the issue, since i am using server control buttons on my aspx page...

Comment: Right, but you could view source in the browser and provide that, instead. Sounds like a client side issue.

Comment: i am trying to find a way to attach the viewsource, after the pageload and after a click_event of a button...

Comment: Ahhh, I take that back, I missed your comment about the page posting back to itself when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: @mikehomme:yup, that's the issue that i am posting back to the same page and i cannot create a new page now to show the post back results...i thought there must be a way to deactivate the modal dialog after the initial page load...

Comment: Well, depending on your requirements, you could use a cookie, session variable, or database flag to suppress it?

Comment: @mikehomme: it's much easier to use a panel to show the initial instructions on a page_load and then suppress that panel and show other things, but i thought, it would be cool to use jquery library for these modals..

Comment: @Ron - couldn't you put the dialog in a function and then register a startup script in your code behind to call the function when the Page.IsPostBack is false and then not have it fire on subsequent postbacks?

Comment: @Gjohn: i can give it a try, tho i'm clueless on how to achieve this..Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Change your javascript to the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    confimationDialogShow: function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 189,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
           Agree: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

On your server do the following in your Page_Load method:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: confimationDialogShow();", true);
}
```

So every time you load the page for the very first time you can fire the startup script and show the dialog. Subsequent postbox from the page will not show the dialog anymore. because the script to call it will only get launched when the IsPostBack value is false.

Happy Coding!!!

### UPDATE

Hey Ron, let's try and take this out of the $(document).ready(). Do this instead.

```
<script>
   function confirmationDialogShow() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
           resizable: false,
           height: 189,
           width: 500,
           modal: true,
           buttons: {
              Agree: function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
              }
           }
        });
   }
</script>
```

See if the Register script will call it now. BTW - your dialog isn't in an asp:UpdatePanel like that?

Comment: awesome, i'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, i am much closer to achieving what i intended, through your insight, but the modal dialog is not showing, and hence i am not able to close the dialog.  I am trouble-shooting this. Will post the outcome.

Comment: after so much of troubleshooting, i am still unable to get the modal popup.

Comment: Hi John, AWESOME !! , It worked, but the content shows up static on the top of the page without the modal, after a button click. So i wrapped the whole content in a panel, and in the page_load, made the visible="false" if it's not a post_back.  Thanks a lot for your help. You saved me !!

Comment: No, my dialog is not inside an Update panel.

Answer (score 0):

since your html code of the page with buttons is missing, i am just guessing.
put `Agree` into quotation marks, like it's done in this [example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

```
   buttons: {
               "Agree": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
```

otherwise your function may apply to all buttons on your page.

Comment: This didn't work.  My html has server control button, and not html button.